# Orthogonal function expansions and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, fourier-series, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider expanding some function $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in terms of say Legendre functions:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n P_n(x)
$$
where the truncation limit $N$ is some large number sufficient to represent $f(x)$ to some desired accuracy. This can be written in terms of a vector dot product:
$$
f(x) = {\bf p}(x)^T {\bf a}
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{p}(x) = \pmatrix{ P_0(x) \\ P_1(x) \\ \vdots \\ P_N(x)}, \qquad
\mathbf{a} = \pmatrix{a_0 \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_N}
$$
Now suppose I want to sample $f(x)$ at some discrete set of points $x \in X = \{x_0, x_1, \dots, x_M\}$, so that
$$
\mathbf{f}(X) = \mathbf{P}(X) \mathbf{a}
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{f}(X) = \pmatrix{ f(x_0) \\ f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_M)}, \qquad
\mathbf{P}(X) = \pmatrix{ \mathbf{p}(x_0)^T \\ \mathbf{p}(x_1)^T \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{p}(x_M)^T} \qquad
$$
My questions are:

1. If I chose $X$ to uniformly sample the interval $[-1,1]$ and let $M,N \rightarrow \infty$, do the eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ converge to some values? Do there exist analytic expressions for these eigenvalues? What about eigenvectors? *Note: Since the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ is $M \times N$, it might make more sense to talk about eigenvalues of $\mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{P}$, or singular values of $\mathbf{P}$ itself.*
2. Is it true that in the limit $M,N \rightarrow \infty$ that $\mathbf{P}$ becomes a linear operator acting on a Hilbert space?
3. What if instead of Legendre functions I use other orthogonal functions, like Laguerre, Chebyshev, spherical harmonics, sines/cosines, etc. Are there any known results about the corresponding linear operators for those basis sets, such as eigenvalues/eigenvectors?
4. Is there a branch of mathematics which studies these types of questions? If so what is it and can anyone recommend good references to learn more about this?

Comment: I don't want to give wrong answers so I won't answer 1. or 2. But for 3, yes using any set of basis functions there are ways to extract information on the eigenpairs. This brings me to 4. You are looking for the field of Numerical Analysis, also known as Scientific Computing. It is a personal favorite of mine. There are loads of textbooks devoted to the topic. I personally enjoyed this textbook by Heath: http://heath.cs.illinois.edu/scicomp/ but I encourage you to look for more/free resources.

Comment: Numerical analysis could certainly find eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a specific matrix (given some $M,N$). However I don't think it has many theoretical results of how the eigenvalues of such matrices converge.

Comment: It depends what you mean. When I studied it, we learned about many numerical methods that offer convergence to eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors, and we learned about what conditions under which they will or will not converge. But if you mean the field doesn't have results that let you analytically state what eigenvalues/vectors will be, you're right; the methods used are iterative in nature.